# anyway to monitor metrics for spark version 2.4.7 which structured streaming tab provides in web ui starting from spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

currently working on end to end pipeline for reading from kafka and loading in sql server , and we are saving offsets in hbase in pyspark. we are using spark structured streaming and using pyspark version 2.4.7 . The structured streaming tab is not getting enabled in the web UI as it was starting from pyspark 3.0 . is there anyway to monitor the metrics like inputrate, scheduling delay,processingtime, total delay metrics which structured streaming tab provides us. how to keep track of kafka batches in this scenario. we are not using any grafana, prothemus tools for monitoring.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'll need to add JMX monitoring like Prometheus or Jolokia, yes. PySpark doesn't matter since you're talking about monitoring the actual JVM that Spark runs in